# I was able to hear the sound/noise from here?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, connotation

Given this question:

> Dude the rock band was awesome.

Which one of *sound* or *noise*  is correct here?

> 1. Yes, I know — I was able to hear the concert’s **noise** from my balcony.
> 2. Yes, I know — I was able to hear the concert’s **sound** from my balcony.

Comment: This depends solely on the listener's perception of the music.

Comment: Don't bother categorizing it. Just say _able to hear the concert from my balcony_. That doesn't mean one could **listen to** the concert from there, but rather that one could hear that it was going on, whether one appreciated the music or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a question of which is correct usage, it’s more a question of what meaning you intend to imply by the choice of those two words.

To use the word *sound* you’re implying something audible.

To use the worse *noise* you’re implying something loud and not harmonious.

Comment: ... wish your audience to infer from your choice ...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Please feel free to edit my answer if it irks you so much.

Comment: @spiceyokooko FTFY.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Ta very much!

Comment: I believe the strict distinction is that the waves formed by a sound are regular, whereas the waves formed by a noise are irregular.

Comment: @spiceyokooko: I'm wondering how you infer irritation on my part? I merely pointed out where a correction was necessary - isn't that partly what this website is about? The understanding of and _correct use of_ English?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, can you clarify that last question? Ie, is it the case you *were*  irritated, and wondered how spiceyokooko figured it out, or you were not irritated and wondered why spiceyokooko thought you were?

Comment: I can't clarify the question - it's clear enough as it stands. Concerning my attitude on seeing the mistake Andrew later corrected - as an ex-teacher, I wouldn't have made it this far if I had let genuine errors get me irritated. Of course, some pupils hated being corrected, and let one know about it.